# ios can I observer ( NSNotificationCenter) from different thread

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, nsnotificationcenter

I have a question for you guys. I was wondering I generate another thread and set NSNotificationCenter to observe a event in the main thread?, what will be the best of doing this?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973106/nsoperation-and-nsnotificationcenter-on-the-main-thread

Comment: in this case they trying to take the notification to the main thread to update UI. In my case I need to observer something in the main thread from different thread.

Answer (score 2):

Notifications are delivered synchronously by the poster. There are no queues involved. When you call `postNotification:`, it will run all the observer code right then, sequentially for all observers, on the current thread, before returning.

If the observer wants to handle the observation on a different queue, then you should use `dispatch_async` or an `NSOperation` in the observer method to move the processing to the appropriate queue and then return.

Comment: in my case if use dispatch_async to create the observer can I observe and event on the main thread?

Comment: Yes. Your notification callback will be called on whatever thread posts the notification. You can then use `dispatch_async` to move your processing over to whatever queue you would like.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle notifications on a specific thread by using `- (id)addObserverForName:(NSString *)name object:(id)obj queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue usingBlock:(void (^)(NSNotification *))block`.

As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/addObserverForName%3aobject%3aqueue%3ausingBlock%3a) states, regarding the queue parameter:

> The operation queue to which block should be added. If you pass nil, the block is run synchronously on the posting thread.